# Talking about colors. Orange juice and a juice of orange color

Tags: phrase-request, attributive-nouns

"Orange juice" is a juice from an orange,

but what if I wanted to say that the juice is orange in color? Can it be also "orange juice"? What are the different ways to talk about a color? I think of "of ... color" but I'd like to know more way to describe and talk about colors. Other expression than "of...color"?

Comment: *Orange-colored juice* works too.

Comment: Juice that is orange.

Comment: Or you could "say the juice is orange in colour". And yes, it can be orange juice. Could you give an example of "of...color" please? Something like "of orange" or "of orange colour"?

Comment: Sure, you can do it if you want to: _“This orange juice was made from mangoes.”_ (If I was saying that aloud, I’d likely change the syllable that I stressed, putting a little extra emphasis on the word _juice_.)

Comment: *Orange juice* (meaning *juice of an orange*) and *orange juice* (meaning *orange-colored juice*) are pronounced differently.